# What happens when Istio ingress gateway has overlapping hosts?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

Say we have below Istio ingress gateway, which is configured with 2 overlapping hosts `*.contoso.com` and `foo.contoso.com`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: external
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
    gateway: external
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: external-cert
    hosts:
    - "*.contoso.com"
    - "foo.contoso.com"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*.contoso.com"
    - "foo.contoso.com"
```

Below are the Virtual Services configured with the above gateway.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: contoso-external
  namespace: contoso
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*.contoso.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-system/external
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: wildcard.contoso.xyz
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: foo-external
  namespace: contoso-foo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "foo.contoso.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-system/external
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: foo.contoso.xyz
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bar-external
  namespace: contoso-bar
spec:
  hosts:
  - "bar.contoso.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-system/external
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: bar.contoso.xyz
```

Interestingly, through the ingress gateway, traffic with host header `foo.contoso.com` will be routed to `wildcard.contoso.xyz` instead of `foo.contoso.xyz`. But traffic with host header `bar.contoso.com` will be routed to `bar.contoso.xyz` correctly.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Why the one I specified in gateway host list fail to use its matching VirtualService, but instead routed through the Virtual Service defined for the wilcard host?